# Not able to run flutter run. Getting some androidx error

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter run command is not working now. It was working 4hrs before. Suddenly something happended. I didn't changed anything. Just added few plugins and removed. Because it was not supporting for my SDK version. Already wasted so much time. Please help me on this issue.[image]

```
    Note: /Users/sunisha/Developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: /Users/sunisha/Developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: /Users/sunisha/Developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity-0.4.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/connectivity/ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.              
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: /Users/sunisha/Developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webview_plugin-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/com/flutter_webview_plugin/WebviewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding, unresolved supertypes: androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
                                                                        
e: /Users/sunisha/Developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/in_app_update-1.1.11/android/src/main/kotlin/de/ffuf/in_app_update/InAppUpdatePlugin.kt: (8, 28): Unresolved reference: NonNull
e: /Users/sunisha/Developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/in_app_update-1.1.11/android/src/main/kotlin/de/ffuf/in_app_update/InAppUpdatePlugin.kt: (55, 38): Unresolved reference: NonNull
e: /Users/sunisha/Developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/in_app_update-1.1.11/android/src/main/kotlin/de/ffuf/in_app_update/InAppUpdatePlugin.kt: (57, 34): Unresolved reference: binaryMessenger
e: /Users/sunisha/Developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/in_app_update-1.1.11/android/src/main/kotlin/de/ffuf/in_app_update/InAppUpdatePlugin.kt: (63, 40): Unresolved reference: NonNull
```

When I run Flutter channel;
[image]

Comment: run `fflutter pub upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old flutter version, change to the stable channel, by executing:

```
flutter channel stable
```

and then upgrade flutter by executing:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Then you can update your packages by doing:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases

Comment: when I run flutter pub upgrade am getting like this;
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2217, change to stable channel and upgrade flutter, the latest version is 1.17 now

Comment: getting like this Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (1 tries left)
Command 'pub upgrade' still failed after 10 tries, giving up.

Comment: Are you connected to a good internet connection? The best thing might be to just download flutter again from the website

Comment: Your flutter checkout has local changes that would be erased by upgrading. If you want to keep these changes, it is recommended that you stash them via "git stash" or else commit
the changes to a local branch. If it is okay to remove local changes, then re-run this command with --force.

Comment: flutter upgrade --force
doing like this

Comment: seems u changed something in the flutter folder that u have, i think the best thing is to install it from the beginning here https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: install it again from here flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216478/discussion-between-sunisha-sindhu-and-peter-haddad).